# Looping through Javascript object to add subtotals based on child objects

Tags: javascript, loops

I have a JavaScript object as follows:

```
{
   "name":"root",
   "children":[
      {
         "name":"Oct 2014",
         "children":[
            {
               "name":"Books",
               "value":106223,
               "formattedValue":"$106,223"
            },
            {
               "name":"Electronics",
               "value":983933,
               "formattedValue":"$983,933"
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "name":"Nov 2014",
         "children":[
            {
               "name":"Books",
               "value":117588.7,
               "formattedValue":"$117,589"
            },
            {
               "name":"Electronics",
               "value":992779,
               "formattedValue":"$992,779"
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

I'm wondering how I can loop through the object's lowest children, and work my way backwards, pragmatically, to add a "value" element to each parent, where the value is the total of the child objects. So in the example above, this is the result I'm trying to get to:

```
{
   "name":"root",
   "children":[
      {
         "name":"Oct 2014",
         "children":[
            {
               "name":"Books",
               "value":106223,
               "formattedValue":"$106,223"
            },
            {
               "name":"Electronics",
               "value":983933,
               "formattedValue":"$983,933"
            }
         ],
         "value":10900156
      },
      {
         "name":"Nov 2014",
         "children":[
            {
               "name":"Books",
               "value":117588.7,
               "formattedValue":"$117,589"
            },
            {
               "name":"Electronics",
               "value":992779,
               "formattedValue":"$992,779"
            }
         ],
         "value":1110367.7
      }
   ]
}
```

Could someone provide guidance in how I can get to the bottom-most children, and add the value of each child to the parent, forming subtotals?

Things I've figured out so far:

- Number children in an object: root.children.length.
- Looping through top children:

```
for(var i = 0; i < root.children.length;i++){
var obj = root.children[i];
console.log("name: "+obj["name"]);
console.log("value: "+obj["value"]);
}
```

Note: the dataset is not guaranteed to always have the same "depth". While in this case the object has 2 levels, in other scenarios it may have more or less. I'm trying to account for that in the loop.

Will update as I figure more things out... thanks for any input anyone can provide in the meantime!

Comment: Recursion is what you looking for

Comment: @hindmost, recursion may not help here because the structure is not consistent from parent to child.

Comment: @loco, are the bottom-most children always going to be 2 levels below the root? If not, please explain.

Comment: @Jonathan M, no unfortunately not. I'm integrating a visualization into an analytics platform. How many children each parent has can vary depending on the dataset used, and these datasets tend to be easily adjustable, so this needs to be dynamic too. But the bottommost children can always be expected to have a value and a name element.

Comment: I was thinking perhaps the full JSON object can be stored in a var. A function could be called to loop through the bottommost parents, and add a sum of the children's value elements to the parent as a value element, if it doesn't have one already. Then work its way backwards until the top parent has a value node with the sum of its children. Still figuring out how to design this function in code.

Comment: @loco, your data structure is inconsistent between parent and child. So what does the structure look like if the bottom-most children are 3 or 4 levels down? Usually, tree structures (which contain multiple parent/child levels) have the same data structure for each node, because each node can be both a parent and a child. That doesn't appear to be the case here.

Comment: The data-structure should be consistent all the way down for each node. There would be a name element, a value element, and a children element if that node has more children.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recursion is indeed what you are looking for.

```
function getChildrenValue (parent) {
   if (parent.children) {
      var value = 0;
      for (var i=0;i<parent.children.length;i++) {
         var child = parent.children[i];
         value += getChildrenValue(child);
      }
      parent.value = value;
   }
   return parent.value;
}

//var root = yourJSONData    
getChildrenValue(root);
console.log(root);
```

Comment: There's a correct algorithmic implementation that we both arrived at individually. I'd argue that my implementation is a little clearer, however.

Answer (score 2):

First of all sorry if did not understand the request correctly.

This is what I tried so far:

```js
var json = {
  "name":"root",
  "children":[
    {
      "name":"Oct 2014",
      "children":[
        {
          "name":"Books",
          "value":106223,
          "formattedValue":"$106,223"
        },
        {
          "name":"Electronics",
          "value":983933,
          "formattedValue":"$983,933"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name":"Nov 2014",
      "children":[
        {
          "name":"Books",
          "value":117588.7,
          "formattedValue":"$117,589"
        },
        {
          "name":"Electronics",
          "value":992779,
          "formattedValue":"$992,779"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
};

(function processCurrent(object) {
  var processResult;

  object.value = object.value || 0;

  if (object.children) {
    for (var i=0;i<object.children.length;i++) {
      if (processResult = processCurrent(object.children[i])) {
        object.value += processResult;
      }
    }
  }

  return object.value;
})(json);

console.log(JSON.stringify(json));
```

This recursively goes through your object and calculates the sum of all children for each node.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, both ways worked, but I preferred the clarity of @J4G's answer.

Answer (score 0):

This will do that for you:

```
var jsonData = {
"name":"root",
"children":[
   {
      "name":"Oct 2014",
      "children":[
         {
            "name":"Books",
            "value":106223,
            "formattedValue":"$106,223"
         },
         {
            "name":"Electronics",
            "value":983933,
            "formattedValue":"$983,933"
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "name":"Nov 2014",
      "children":[
         {
            "name":"Books",
            "value":117588.7,
            "formattedValue":"$117,589"
         },
         {
            "name":"Electronics",
            "value":992779,
            "formattedValue":"$992,779"
         }
      ]
   }
]
}

jsonData.children.map(function (obj) {
    return obj.value = obj.children.reduce(function(prev, cur){
       return prev.value + cur.value;
    })
})
console.log(jsonData);
```